# When using ThreadLocal it always returns null, although when debbaged it shows that it is actually gets initialized with a value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, threadpool

I want first to mention that when I first implemented it, it was working fine, now it is not and I don't know what the things I changed that stopped it from working.
I am working on a Spring boot project that uses JPA and hibernate, I want to get the **MetadataImplementor** from Hibernate.
I created a class that catches it during initialization and put it in a ThreadLocal, here is the code that does that:

```
public class HibernateMetadata implements SessionFactoryBuilderFactory {
    private static final ThreadLocal<MetadataImplementor> metadataImplementor = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public SessionFactoryBuilder getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImplementor metadataImplementor,
                                                          SessionFactoryBuilderImplementor defaultBuilder) {
        HibernateMetadata.metadataImplementor.set(metadataImplementor);
        return defaultBuilder;
    }

    public static MetadataImplementor getMetadataImplementor() {

        return metadataImplementor.get();
    }
}
```

This class always gets called during startup and the **MetadataImplementor** configured by hibernating gets put in the ThreadLocal, I am sure of that, I debugged it and it showed me it does this during startup.
It was working fine, now suddenly it stopped and it always returns null.
If I try to get the **MetadataImplementor** from within another service code as the following, it returns **null**:

```
@Override
    public void introspect(Class<?> klass, Map<String, Property> properties) {
        // ...

        MetadataImplementor metadataImplementor = HibernateMetadata.getMetadataImplementor(); // this returns null

        if (metadataImplementor == null) {
            return; // it always returns null and return
        }

        PersistentClass persistentClass = metadataImplementor.getEntityBinding(klass.getName());

        Iterator<?> propertyIterator = persistentClass.getPropertyClosureIterator();

        while (propertyIterator.hasNext()) {
            Property property = createProperty(klass, (org.hibernate.mapping.Property) propertyIterator.next(),
                metamodelImplementor);
            properties.put(property.getName(), property);
        }
    // ...
    }
```

If I don't use the ThreadLocal and I directly use the **metadataImplementor** instead, it gets initialized and it works.
I think it's like it was calling it from another thread, I don't know, Can anyone point me towards what I am missing here?.

Comment: By storing it into a `ThreadLocal` you are storing the value exactly for the currently running thread (the thread calling `getSessionFactoryBuilder()`, which probably is just doing some initialization).  Every other thread that later calls `getMetadataImplementor()` will get its thread-specific value of the ThreadLocal - which probably was never initialized.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, okay, I get it, but why it was working fine previously, now it's not and I can't recall what I have changed that made it stop working.

Comment: It seems that the later code was previously running in the same thread as the initialization but is no longer. Why do you need to store it in a `ThreadLocal` if storing it in a field directly works?